# Cartopy set_extent is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to use Mateplotlib cartopy to make the plots below. Here is the code that I am using.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,11))
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))
mm =   ax.contourf(new_lon[:],lat_post,new_aa[0,:,:],transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))

ax.coastlines(resolution='10m');
ax.stock_img();
# the following two lines increaes the vertical distance between the title and the upper tick.
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.titlepad']=20
# drawing the longitude and latitude ticks.
gl = ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0), draw_labels=True,linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
```

[image]
Yet, once I add the following code set_extent
`ax.set_extent([np.min(new_lon),np.max(new_lon),np.min(lat_post)
,np.max(lat_post)])`

The figures becomes like that 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your original map, it looks like there's a seam at 0 longitude, so I'm guessing `np.min(new_lon)` is 0, and `np.min(new_lon)` is 360. If you use that with `set_extent()`, you're getting a really narrow strip at the prime meridian. I'm guess if you do `set_extent([-180, 180, ,np.min(lat_post), np.max(lat_post)]` it will work better.

The only way I can think of to achieve it programmatically in this case is to do:

```
lon_bounds = new_lon[:]  # copy
lon_bounds[lon_bounds > 180] -= 360
ax.set_extent([np.min(lon_bounds), np.max(lon_bounds), np.min(lat_post), np.max(lat_post)])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. the                                                                    `set_extent([-180,180, np.min(lat_post), np.max(lat_post)]`                solved the problem. On the other hand the last codes gave me a distorted shapes. As you expected new_lon starts at 0 and ends at 358.40955.  I am wondering why set_extent have a problem at all when lon starts at 0 and end at 360.

Comment: The problem is that when you set the extents to 0 and 360, when it converts those values to the projection, they end up right next to each other. Another option, if you know you always want to display the entire globe, you an also do: `ax.set_global()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it.

Answer (score 1):

The set_extent works by giving deviations from central longitude and latitude. For example, if the central longitude is 100E, then

```
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=100)

ax.set_extent([-50,50,-30,30], crs=proj)
```

will produce map for longitude 50E to 150E and latitude 30S to 30N.